# changing graphing symbols in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, charts, symbols, triangle

What do I need to call to change my symbols in a Fastpoint VB.net chart? It auto selects circles squares triangles and diamonds at random. However, I am needing them all to be diamonds and or triangles is this even possible?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

All one line and you can change the diamond to anything you need it to be. This goes where you are setting up your series.

```
MyChart.Series("Series Name").MarkerStlye = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Diamond
```